# XAML Cannot set value of property of base class from a different assembly

Tags: c#, xaml

It can be hard to come up with a succinct title!

I have two WPF projects in a single Solution. The first, a WpfApplication defines Class1. The second, a WpfControlLibrary defines Class2 which inherits from Class1, Class3 which inherits from Class2, and UserControl1. They are shown below:

**WpfApplication Class1**

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**WpfControlLibrary Class2 and Class3**

```
namespace WpfControlLibrary1
{
  public class Class2
  {
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
  }
  public class Class3 : Class2
  {
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In summary, Class 1 has Property1, Class2 has Property1 (thru inheritance) and Property2, and Class3 has Property1 and Property2 (both thru inheritance) and Property3. The XAML for the user control is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:b="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5;assembly=WpfApplication5"
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <UserControl.Resources>
      <b:Class1 x:Key="test1" Property1="xxx" />
      <l:Class2 x:Key="test2" Property1="xxx" Property2="yyy" />
      <l:Class3 x:Key="test3" Property2="yyy" Property3="zzz" />
      <l:Class3 x:Key="test4">
        <l:Class3.Property1>xxx</l:Class3.Property1>
        <l:Class3.Property2>yyy</l:Class3.Property2>
        <l:Class3.Property3>zzz</l:Class3.Property3>
      </l:Class3>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>

  </Grid>
```

The problem is that the XAML wont compile, and gives the following error:

```
The property 'Property1' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1'.
The property 'Property1' was not found in type 'Class2'.
The attachable property 'Property1' was not found in type 'Class3'.
```

It looks like XAML can't cope with a property that is inherited from a different assembly. Is this right, or have I been looking at it for too long. I have tried the different forms of setting Property1 and event tried `b:Property1=` and `b:Class1.Property1=` but none seem to work.
Or have I been looking at this for too long and over-complicated things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to add my own answer here to try and explain what I think happened, despite my bad example I quoted above, for anybody else that happens by.

When you instantiate an object from a different assembly using XAML, the namespace looks like the following:

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5;assembly=WpfApplication5"
```

Notice it has the assembly named. It also seems to copy the assembly into the bin folder. In my case, something crazy happened and the assembly that was copied in was hours old. Consequently, even though the c# could compile, the XAML couldn't. Some magic happened whereby the build for this assembly was mysteriously unchecked in the Configuration Manager. However, checking it again and rebuilding still didn't rebuild the exe. During this excitement, Visual Studio crashed and restarted (is it just me or does this happen a lot with VS2010).

In the end I had to remove all of the DLL projects and build the main app by itself. Then I could add the DLL projects back in and compile. Then it all worked as expected.

Comment: Ha! I just accepted this because it was the real problem. It is always helpful when people help. Thanks